Constructing a secondary axis on in R ggplot
I need to generate two lines on one graph. One variable - T is plotted as the primary axis and I am looking to create a secondary axis for the variable ZP.
The dataframe is as follows:
particle_effect



AD
RT
ZP




0
20
-34


1
12
-30


2
10
-27


3
8
-25


4
6
-20


5
4
-12


6
2
-6


7
1
-2




I am trying to set the range of the T variable in the primary Y-axis from 0 to 75 and the secondary Y-axis for ZP from -50 to 0. Everything that I have tried with the sec.axis function changes both the Y-axis ranges. I might be getting something wrong but am not being able to identify it. I would appreciate the help!
particle_effect %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = AD)+
  geom_point(aes(y=TR),size = 2, alpha = 0.75)+
  geom_point(aes(y=zp),size = 2, alpha = 0.75)+
  geom_line(aes(y=TR))+
  geom_line(aes(y=zp))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "T", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.,name = "ZP"))+
  theme_bw()


This sort of presentation can be difficult to interpret correctly, and may lead to inappropriate conclusions. However, it is still possible to construct with ggplot2. The secondary axis is a transformation of the primary, and to make this work you need to adjust the values on the 2nd axis prior to plotting. Below I set ZP = ZP + 50 and when creating the sec_axis, subtract 50.
This graphic gives the impression that the two series cross between AD=0 and AD=1, despite them being at their closest at AD=7.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

particle_effect |>
  mutate(ZP = ZP + 50) |>
  pivot_longer(-AD) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = AD, y = value, group = name, color = name)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.75) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'T',sec.axis = sec_axis(~.-50, name = 'ZP', breaks = seq(0,-50,-10))) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(color = '') +
  theme(legend.position = 'top')


Created on 2024-05-06 with reprex v2.1.0

Considerable easier using base graphics.
> par(mar=c(4, 4, 2, 4))
> with(particle_effect, plot(AD, TR, ylim=c(0, 75), type='o', pch=20, las=1, 
+                            axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, col=2))
> box()
> axis(1); mtext('AD', 1, 2); 
> axis(2, las=1, col=2, col.axis=2); mtext('T', 2, 2, col=2)
> par(new=TRUE)
> with(particle_effect, plot(AD, zp, ylim=c(-50, 0), type='o', pch=20, 
+                            axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, col=3))
> axis(4, las=1, col=3, col.axis=3); mtext('ZP', 4, 2.5, col=3)
> legend('topleft', legend=c('T', 'ZP'), col=2:3, lty=1, bty='n')



Data:
> dput(particle_effect)
structure(list(AD = 0:7, TR = c(20L, 12L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
1L), zp = c(-34L, -30L, -27L, -25L, -20L, -12L, -6L, -2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

